# Iframe ContentWindow

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web

When I try to get the contentwindow out of an iframe, using

```
var contentWindow = document.getElementbyId('iframe').contentWindow
```

sometimes it returns "Window undefined" because the contentWindow doesn't exist.  I can't seem to run a check for it using

```
if (contentWindow === unidentified) or if (contentWindow === null)
```

as it just errors out of the code if I try to grab values out of it.  Has anyone else run into this problem and figured out a solution?

Comment: `unidentified` made me smile :) We were all beginners once.

Answer (score 6):

Are you typing it properly? `getElementByID` not `getElementbyId`. Did you confirm that that returns an element before querying `contentWindow`? Are you querying it after it loads?

Are you doing `gEBI` after DOM ready or page load? Did you throw in alerts on the element? Is the domain in the iframe the same as the origin domain? What browser are you using?

```
if (contentWindow === unidentified) or if (contentWindow === null)
```

There is no such thing as `unidentified` it's `undefined`. Slow down and be accurate.

Answer (score 2):

**Try** this

```
var iframeElem = parent.document.getElementById("iframe");
var win = iframeElem.contentWindow;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try specifying what data you want from the object you call here

```
var contentWindow = document.getElementById('iframe')
```

by doing this

```
var contentWindow = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow
```

This worked for me